# How can I create a web form using Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007, templates

I have a Word file that I want use on a website.

I want to convert it to template with fields.

I created a template with multiple fields, but they are not named for use on the website.

How can I create a template with special field names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe Word can be used as an HTML editor to create web forms, and I suspect that creating a layout then editing the resulting exporting HTML would be more difficult than creating a true HTML form in the first place. That also doesn't provide you with any of the server backend for receiving data submitted using the form.

If you already have the form created in Word, your simplest option for using it online is probably to upload it to [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com) and see about converting it from there into a web form using their tools (which I believe will give you results in a Google Sheets spreadsheet).

Comment: Thanks, in my project, should save malty word file, but my solution is : save a template with fields and save filed value to database. i should set field name for save value in db.

Comment: Malty? Do you mean multiple ("multi")? Word's Template (.dot/.dotx) files aren't really built for saving to databases, they're designed as document templates so that you can use one to create a new unnamed document that will then have to be saved as a new Word .doc/.docx file. Are you intending to have people save Word documents (.docx) then you're going to extract the data from each document? That may be possible, but I've never heard of anyone doing it and I'm not sure the tools are well suited to it. Word's database connections are mostly to get data into Word (e.g. for Mail Merge).

Comment: I want to save a Template word with malty fields in server, and set name for every fields.(solution: save value from every fileds in database).

Comment: I think http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/extract_data_from_document_file.html is exactly what you're trying to do, but also look at http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/content_controls.html for more useful information and links and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157891.aspx on Content Controls.